# Hamiltonian minimization

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

According to Pontryagin principal of minimality the optimal control minimizes the Hamiltonian along the optimal trajectory.

A Hamiltionan is given by $\mathcal{H}=p^Tf + \mathcal{L}$ for costate vector $p$, Lagranian $\mathcal{L}$ and dynamics $f$.

We also have that the costate and the optimal trajectory should satisfy the canonical equations, $p^{'}=-\mathcal{H}_{x}$ and $x^{'}=\mathcal{H}_{p}$

All the above should apply while evaluation the Hamiltonian along the optimal trajectory i.e the one produced by the optimal control.

To the question,

How are we suppose to find a minima given that both the state and the costate ultimately depends on $u$? What do we plug in for $p$ and $x$ in the Hamiltonian when minimizing over $u$?

I find this hard to consider since both $p$ and $x$ might depends on $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the following objective function

$$J = \varphi(\boldsymbol{x}(t_\text{f}),t_\text{f}) + \int_{t_0}^{t_\text{f}}\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),t)dt,$$

in which $\varphi(\boldsymbol{x}(t_\text{f}),t_\text{f})$ is the terminal cost depending on the final state $\boldsymbol{x}(t_\text{f})$ at final time $t_\text{f}$ and $\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),t)$ denoting the Lagranian which is also a function of the control input vector $\boldsymbol{u}(t)$.

If we want to determine the control input $\boldsymbol{u}(t)$ that minimizes $J$ subject to the dynamics of the system

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}(t)=\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),t)$$

with free initial condition $\boldsymbol{x}(t_0)$ and final condition $\boldsymbol{x}(t_\text{f})$, then we need to apply the following steps (taken from the book Optimal Control Systems (2003) by Desineni Subbaram Naidu, page 69).

Step 1: Determine the Hamiltonian

$$\mathcal{H}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),\boldsymbol{\lambda}(t),t)=\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),t)+\boldsymbol{\lambda}^T(t)\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),t).$$

Step 2: Determine the optimal control input $\boldsymbol{u}^*(t)=\boldsymbol{k}(\boldsymbol{x}^*(t),\boldsymbol{\lambda}^*(t),t)$ by minimize $\mathcal{H}$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{u}(t)$.
$$\boldsymbol{u}^*(t)={\displaystyle {\underset {\boldsymbol{u}(t)}{\operatorname {arg\,min} }}} \,\,\mathcal{H}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),\boldsymbol{\lambda}(t),t)$$
Note, this condition can be simplifed to 
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{u}(t)}\mathcal{H}(\boldsymbol{x}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t),\boldsymbol{\lambda}(t),t)=0$$
for unconstraied optimization.

Step 3: Determine the optimal Hamiltonian by using the optimal control $\boldsymbol{u}^*(t)$.

$$\mathcal{H}^*(\boldsymbol{x}^*(t),\boldsymbol{u}^*(t),\boldsymbol{\lambda}^*(t),t)$$

Step 4: Solve the state and costate equation

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}^*(t)=+\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{H}^*}{\partial \boldsymbol{\lambda}^*}$$
$$\dot{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}^*(t)=-\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{H}^*}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}^*}$$

with the initial condition $\boldsymbol{x}_0$ and the final conditions

$$\left[\mathcal{H}^*+\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} \right]^{}_{t_\text{f}}\delta t_\text{f}+\left[ \left(\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}\right)^*-\boldsymbol{\lambda}^*(t)\right]^T_{t_\text{f}}\delta \boldsymbol{x}_\text{f}=0.$$

In the last equation $\delta t_\text{f}$ and $\delta \boldsymbol{x}_\text{f}$ are variations which vanish if the final time or the final state is fixed, hence does not permit any variation.

Step 5: Determine the optimal control $\boldsymbol{u}^*(t)$ by substituting $\boldsymbol{x}^*(t)$ and $\boldsymbol{\lambda}^*(t)$ into

$$\boldsymbol{u}^*(t)=\boldsymbol{k}(\boldsymbol{x}^*(t),\boldsymbol{\lambda}^*(t),t).$$

Comment: It looks like the optimal control in step 2 depends on the solutions in step 4 and this is whats confusing to me. As far as I know $u$ should only minimize H given optimal path $x^{*}$ and some costate associsated to the seperating hyperplan $p^{*}$. Minimizing H w.r.t maybe in many cases depend on properties of $p$.

Comment: On the hand the differential equation for $p^{*}$ depends on $u^{*}$, in general..

Comment: You should do some examples. This procedure only yields a closed form solution for pretty easy problems.

Comment: I really do not get your problem. If you are able to determine the control law in step 2 it will only depend on $x(t),\lambda(t),t$. Hence, your Hamiltonian does not depend on $u(t)$. And you can solve the state equation and the costate equation which are only in $x^*(t),\lambda^*(t),t$.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no constraints on $u$ then Pontryagin's principle also states $H_u = 0$, which can be solved for $u$. If there are constraints then you can use the following [definition](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/courses/amath579/Maximum.pdf) in general

$$
u^* = \arg\min_u H(x,u,p).
$$

Comment: Are you saying it minimizes the hamiltionan for all $p$ and $x$ aswell? As far as I understand this should hold on the optimal path and for the associated costate.

Comment: @MadMax You still have to find the initial conditions of the costate, which might depend on the constraint of the final state. Since you did not specified this in your question I left this out of my answer. Also the linked pdf I think also gives a proof for this.

Comment: So suppose we know that there in fact is a solution. Then we really need alot of info on the costate to be able to produce a control, right? And unless we know that this solution is unique this donst really give us anything? We would need that there is a unique solution and get full info on the costate to be able to conclude that we found the control